# visual studio resources paste column

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, copy-paste

I'm using the resource editor in visual studio. I'm trying to copy the values from the value column of one resource file and paste them in the comment column of another resource file.

I've tried using `SHIFT+ALT` which copies the column correctly, but then the paste doesn't work as expected (instead of pasting in the comment col. , new keys are generated)

Is this possible? If so how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since paste wasn't working in the visual studio resource editor, I pasted the values column data in a google docs spreadsheet and that worked.

Comment: so I guess it's not possible in the visual studio resx editor

Comment: See my answer below!